# PHP: is it possible to callback like in C++?

Tags: php, callback

Im not sure it this is possible in PHP…

I basically want

```
// A.php

class A {
    public static function foo(int a, string b) {
        //…//
    }
}
```

to be given to another function in another class. *But* that other class should not be aware of class A and should not need to include it and instead only specify something like this…

```
// B.php

class B {
    public static function doSomething(callable $fn) {
        $fn(1,'test'); //<-error
    }
}
```

Currently I get the error "Class A" not found when I call it with…

```
include_once('A.php');
include_once('B.php');
B::doSomething('A::foo');
```

Comment: [Tested your code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c2962cd90665a1c3d23b0e3d740078ae19323d8) and it seems to work?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thats because you put it in one file, there – of course – A is known to B and vice versa.

Comment: OK, so what have you done that it doesn't work?

Comment: Try using [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) to execute the callable inside your `doSomething()` method. Like this: `call_user_func($fn, 1, 'test');`. That will work on any callable and not just the string you've posted.

Comment: I took the effort to run the code in my test on my own server, in three separate files, as you described, and it still works fine. I think your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: It's simple, you could have tested your own code before you asked this question. That would have told you there are minor syntax errors in it, which tells me that you didn't do this. You probably tried to write some abstract code to capture your problem, but your problem is something else. Testing something yourself would have told you that.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP can do callbacks, but I'm not sure if you can do it via classname.

Here's a really simple example:

```
function Test($mystring) {return "MY STRING = ".$myString;}
function CallMyFunction($functionname,$mydata) 
{
  echo $functionname($mydata);
}

CallMyFunction('Test',"Hello World!");
```

More info here:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_callback_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

The clue was that it seems to do string to function resolvement in the context of the called class, so calling

```
B::doSomething([A::class, 'foo']);
```

does it in the context, where A is knewn. At least thats my understanding :D

Comment: They say: "Context is everything". 